# Basic d3js max returning multiple values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to get just one value from d3's max function but it's returning an entire array. Here is an example:

```
var data = {
    "Jim" : [
        {
            "Value" : [10,11,12]
        }
    ]
}

var myMax = d3.max(data.Jim, function(d){
        var maxVal = d["Value"];

        return maxVal;
    })

    console.log(myMax + "max")
```

It returns 10,11,12max. It should return 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're trying to find the maximum of the array `data.Jim` which only has one element = `{"Value" : [10,11,12]}` which d3 promptly returns as the maximum using your given accessor function. Try changing your code to the following:

```
var myMax = d3.max(data.Jim, function(d){
    var maxVal = d3.max(d["Value"]);
    return maxVal;
})
```

Comment: Yes. This is correct. d3 is powerful; I just haven't quite grasped it all yet. Thanks though.